# Php/Doctrine array hydration

Tags: php, doctrine

According to the Doctrine [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/working-with-models/en#fetching-objects), you should use Array hydration rather than record hydration when retrieving data for read-only purposes.

Unfortunately, this means I have to use array syntax (as opposed to object syntax) to reference the data.

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Post p')
    ->leftJoin('p.PostComment pc')
    ->leftJoin('pc.User u')
    ->where('p.post_id = ?', $id);

$p = $q->fetchOne(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

...

foreach ($p['PostComment'] as $comment) {
    $this->Controls->Add(new CommentPanel($comment['text'], 
                         $comment['User']['nickname'], 
                         $comment['last_updated_ts']));
}
```

Maybe it's just me, but all of those string literals as array indexes are kinda scary.  Does anyone have some ideas for cleaning this up?

Comment: from what i understand if you would fetch an object you would to $comment->text; or would you do $comment->getText() ? (Not to familiar with the "old/current" doctrine ;) )

Comment: @edorian: It would be `$comment->text;`

Comment: I believe you can use all three.

Comment: I was trying to write a longer answer but it really bowls down to "cast to stdClass (and thats already said now) if you don't like it" but maybe i don't get your reasoning behind that looking "scary". The difference between -> and [''] shoudn't matter so much ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scary?  In what way?  I don't really get that.

It's just syntax.  If you really care, just cast the arrays as stdClass objects

```
foreach ( $p['PostComment'] as $comment )
{
  $comment = (object) $comment;
  $this->Controls->Add( new CommentPanel(
      $comment->text
    , $comment->User->nickname
    , $comment->last_updated_ts
  ));
}
```

Comment: He'd need to cast User to an object too, else it would be $comment->User["nickname"];  But yeah, casting it was also in my mind

Comment: I guess I'm just used to other languages where a typo in a literal would not be caught until run time but a typo in a property name would be caught at compile time.  But with a scripting language like PHP both will not be noticed until run time.

Comment: If that's the concern, you could use define()s or constants to reference your fields, rather than string literals. But that's probably only making things worse. Object hydration may take a little more time and memory but unless you have problems with either, I'd still use it for the very reason you outline here.